# Anylogic, agents waiting in queue

Tags: java, anylogic

I got 100 agents that are directed to a specific node in a network. The network consist of nodes, attractors and paths.

The problem is; when the agent is going to their node, they are not considering other agents (persons) in the network. I want them to stop if the agent in front of them stops.

I use process modeling library and the line is as follows:

-source
-move to
-delay (the agent stop for a moment on one node)
-move to (specific node)
-delay (stays in the specific node)

I tried to create a FIFO queue before the delay, but I do not know how to create that for the whole network. Or is it possible to make a statechart for the agents?

PS. I'm new with Anylogic and javacoding.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Depending on what you actually want to represent there will be lots of different approaches. However, since you state that you want agents to "queue before the delay", that sounds to me like a classical [service with queues](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fmarkup%2FService_Lines.html). You can find those elements in the pedestrian library of AnyLogic.

Comment: Hi @Florian,

I tried your approach but it did not work as I wanted.. maybe I'm doing something wrong. But take e.g. the Aircraft example in "How-to-models" in Anylogic. When the person in the front has luggage, the other agents behind do not stop. Can i still use service with queues and how?